# Haskell indentation block "last statement in a do-block must be an expression"

Tags: haskell, indentation

I am very confused about haskell indentation especially `do` block with `let` and `where`

I got the following error on line `action <-` "last statement in a do-block must be an expression" How should I fix this?

I have the following definition

```
type NeovimRead = Neovim r st Text
type NeovimWrite = Text -> Neovim r st ()

consumeLoop :: Server -> NeovimRead -> NeovimWrite -> Neovim r st ()
consumeLoop server read write = do
    status <- liftIO $ takeMVar (status server)
    if status == Running
       then loop
       else liftIO $ putMVar (status server) status
  where loop = do
    action <- liftIO $ readaction server
    case action of
      ReadBuffer -> do
        text <- read
        liftIO $ putMVar (buffer server) text
      WriteBuffer -> do
        text <- liftIO $ takeMVar (buffer server)
        write text
    liftIO $ putMVar (status server) Running
    consumeLoop server read write
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The body of `loop` needs to be indented more than its name. e.g.:

```
consumeLoop :: Server -> NeovimRead -> NeovimWrite -> Neovim r st ()
consumeLoop server read write = do
    status <- liftIO $ takeMVar (status server)
    if status == Running
       then loop
       else liftIO $ putMVar (status server) status
  where
    loop = do
      action <- liftIO $ readaction server
      ...
```

Comment: Thanks. But is there a reason why it is the case?

Comment: Because it was as if the body of the `do` block was not part of the function, and therefor it was as though you had an empty `do` block, which is why you got the error message you did.